# Magento 2.2 - Removing header and footer ONLY from the home page?

Tags: php, magento2.2

I'm using Magento 2.2, and I'm wondering, how would I remove the header and footer ONLY from the home page? I use various stores, so the home page just acts as a portal to each store.

I explicitly **only** want to remove the header and footer from the home page. They should appear on all other pages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beste way of doing this is to remove the header and footer from your XML-Rendering file. If you only hide it with CSS then this section will be rendered and need some resources. You can try something like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body> 
      <referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="true" />  
      <referenceBlock name="footer.container" remove="true" />
  </body> 
</page>
```

Comment: Question is, where do I put this code? If I put it in:

`app/design/frontend/New_Theme/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Then that'll apply it to the entire site, right?

Comment: Yes in your Theme XML file.

Comment: Right, but if I put it there, it'll remove it throughout the entire site. I ONLY want to remove it for the home page. The rest of the site should have the header and footer.

Comment: When you have a CMS-Page for your Startpage then you can add the remove statements on the extended options. There should be a Layout field where you can edit the both lines for removing the container.

Answer (score 2):

You need to overwrite cms_index_index.xml layout. Then it will apply change only to home index page

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other ways of not rendering the content in the backend code, but you can certainly do it in CSS as well.

```
.cms-home .header {
    display: none;
}

.cms-home .page-footer {
    display: none;
}
```

If you're looking for a code solution, I believe you would override one of the xml layout files to do this.  It has been a while since I have done anything with Magento, so I'm not sure if that's possible, but it should be if I remember correctly.

This looks like it could be a good example to go on for removing it using the layout xml option: [How to remove 'Subscribe' field from Luma footer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164340/how-to-remove-subscribe-field-from-luma-footer)